# How Can I Triger Change Event For HTML Select (Dropdown)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML page has a Button and a Select Drop-Down (Combo Box). Drop-Down change event is like this:

```
$('#DDL_ID').on('change', function (e) {
    // Some Code Here
});
```

When I click the button, I am setting some value to Drop-Down and it is working fine.

```
$('#BTN_ID').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#DDL_ID').val('123');
});
```

When I click the button, Drop-Down value is getting changed but Drop-Down change event is not firing. Can anyone help me on this?

Please note this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: this change event wont trigger change event

Answer (score 1):

Setting the [`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value) through jquery will not automatically trigger the event on the item... so you need to manually [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) it...

```
$('#BTN_ID').on('click', function (e) {
  $('#DDL_ID').val('123').trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Not a problem @A.M.Roomi - good luck with the rest of your project